# How to store and exchange big firestore data between seperate components in angular?

Tags: database, angular, components, google-cloud-firestore

I have a long length array of numbers in firestore. This array is also just one of the property of my object model.

3 of my components on different pages need this array;

- 1st component doesn't need this array but needs another properties of my object model. So i have to fetch it from firestore without any other reason.

-2nd component needs this array to reduce its values and display result on the page.

-3rd component needs to display whole array data.

What is the optimized way to store and exchange these data between those components to avoid any memory leaks or unnecesary firestore calls (free calls are very limited and it makes my web app much more slower)??

I tried to assign this object to my service but hence it is an observable i had to subscribe to it everytime a component needs this data.

Need your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay with using the obervables, so you can make sure that the state within your forms stays in sync with your array data. If you start moving copies of your array around you would have to establish additional state management like Ngrx etc. to achieve this. Also Firestore has a caching feature built in, so it's not always reading data from the server.

Cheers,
Lars

Comment: Thanks. Does firebase cache same query result by default or do i need to implement any persistency logic?

Comment: You can enable offline data in Firestore. See the official docs for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline